# How can I make a bot not case sensitive in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This includes prefixes and commands and pretty much anything you type into in Discord. Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.member
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="bot ")
TOKEN = "4893285903457897349857938275732985" #not a valid token by the way :)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.command(name='image', help='Example command')
async def image(ctx):
    #code for function goes here
    pass


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bot commands can be case *in*sensitive however there is no feature in discord.py to make prefixes case *in*sensitive. However, there is a way to work around this.

**Making bot commands case *in*sensitive**

Change `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix!")`

to: `bot = commands.Bot(case_insensitive=True, command_prefix="prefix!")`

**Making prefixes case *in*sensitive**

I honestly don't really recommend this but if you really need case *in*sensitive prefixes, follow the code below

Create a function called `mixedCase()`

```
def mixedCase(*args):
  """
  Gets all the mixed case combinations of a string

  This function is for in-case sensitive prefixes
  """
  total = []
  import itertools
  for string in args:
    a = map(''.join, itertools.product(*((c.upper(), c.lower()) for c in       string)))
    for x in list(a): total.append(x)

  return list(total)
```

Now modify `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix!")`

to `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=mixedCase("prefix!"))`

### The final code

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.member
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
from discord.utils import get

def mixedCase(*args):
  """
  Gets all the mixed case combinations of a string

  This function is for in-case sensitive prefixes
  """
  total = []
  import itertools
  for string in args:
    a = map(''.join, itertools.product(*((c.upper(), c.lower()) for c in string)))
    for x in list(a): total.append(x)

  return list(total)

bot = commands.Bot(case_insensitive=True, command_prefix=mixedCase("prefix" ))
TOKEN = "4893285903457897349857938275732985" #not a valid token by the way :)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.command(name='image', help='Example command')
async def image(ctx):
    #code for function goes here
    pass


bot.run(TOKEN)
```